# Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am learning spring-boot by reading tutorials on the official website `http://spring.io`. When I tried to implement a service discovery client, I got this error information:`Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.`. I read lots of solutions on Google but none of them helped. Can you give me some advice? I am new to spring-boot.
Here is my code:
-  The spring-boot application class

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class DiscoveryClientApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryClient.class, args);
    }
}
```

- The controller class:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @RequestMapping("service-instances/{appName}")
    public List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstanceByApplicationName(@PathVariable
                                                                      String applicationName) {
        return this.discoveryClient.getInstances(applicationName);
    }

}
```

- And the application.properties

```
server.port = 20000


eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address = true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka = true
eureka.client.fetch-registry = true
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone = http://localhost:8761/eureka

spring.application.name = service-discovery-client

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.datasource-url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring-test
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 80966cc9

spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

My project is a maven project and the discovery client is a sub-project, it's pom.xml is inherited from the father project. In the father project, I added all dependencies. The two other sub-projects run normally, only this service can't run.

Comment: Assuming that you have a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web` in your `pom.xml`, I would guess that Maven corrupted one of Tomcat's jars when it downloaded them. Try clearing out Maven's local cache and rebuilding your application.

Comment: My problem was solved. Thank you very much.